# Submit a row of a table to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table border>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>123456789</td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name = 'select' value = '1' required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Taylor</td>
        <td>012345678</td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name = 'select' value = '2' required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Robert</td>
        <td>Lewis</td>
        <td>901234567</td>
        <td><input type = 'radio' name = 'select' value = '3' required></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is dynamically generated.

I want to submit only the row associated with the radio button that I press to my PHP script. How can I do it in (if possible) **pure** HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you encountered any issue? Seems like you are looking for someone to do this for you.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. I've seen examples that use jQuery, but I have no experience in that language and I don't know how I could solve my problem in pure HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: this is not clear what you want , please clear what you actual want?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam When I press one of the three radio buttons, I want to post all the values of its row to a PHP script.

Comment: When you press any radio button then send to all radio button data?

Comment: ok got your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to add onclick function then add count in function value

```
<table border id="table1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Telephone</th>
<th>Select</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>123456789</td>
<td><input type = 'radio' id="id1" name = 'select' value = '1' required onclick="getAllData(1)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mary</td>
<td>Taylor</td>
<td>012345678</td>
<td><input type = 'radio' id="id2" name = 'select' value = '2' required onclick="getAllData(2)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Robert</td>
<td>Lewis</td>
<td>901234567</td>
<td><input type = 'radio' id="id3" name = 'select' value = '3' required onclick="getAllData(3)"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function getAllData(id_value){
   var table = document.getElementById("table1");
   FirstName = table.rows[id_value].cells[0].innerHTML;                
   LastName = table.rows[id_value].cells[1].innerHTML;
   phone = table.rows[id_value].cells[2].innerHTML;
    alert(FirstName+"=="+LastName+"=="+phone);
  window.location.href="edit.php?FirstName="+FirstName+"&LastName="+LastName+"&phone="+phone;
   }
  </script>
```

then create edit.php page or you can change page name then add this code , one thing page path need to correct

```
print_r($_GET);
```

then you can see all data for your row

Comment: please check my answer